# Application with a server side and client side: how to redirect data from server side to client side?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I should implement an application that provides a service to some clients and, at the same time, communicates with other remote services. In other words, this application should be servers for its clients, but it should also be a client of the remote services. I should use NetTcpBinding with callbacks both for the communication to the remote services and for the communication with clients:

- it should send requests to the remote services and receive responses from them with callbacks;
- it should receive requests from the clients and send responses to them using callbacks.

These two types of communication should be developed on separate threads, but need to access (read and write) to shared data concurrently: for example, when the application receives data from the clients, it should "redirect" some of these data to some of the remote services.

I could implement the two sides of the application in two separate threads, and use one or more singleton objects to share common data received from clients or from remote services. I could use a shared `Queue<T>` as singleton object (where `T` is the type of data received from remote services or from clients): in this way, when my service application receive data from a client, it will enqueue the received data; similarly, when it receives data from a remote service, puts them in the same queue; finally, the enqueued data are read: some data are sent to remote services, while other data are sent to clients.

1. I think I need a `Queue<T>` shared object.
2. Then I need a thread where instantiate the `ServiceHost` for the clients.
3. And another thread where instantiate the proxy for the `ServiceHost` of the remote services.

   - Is it correct? Or are there simpler, more efficient or more OOP solutions?
   - How to handle the redirection of data in the queue? In theory, any data received (from a remote service or a client) may be processed immediately and redirected, but the problem is that the server side (which receives data from clients) might use the client side in order to redirect some of the data to remote services, but the client side may be busy receiving data from some other remote service.

Could you advise me of any complete examples available on the internet?

Comment: What you write sounds more or less reasonable. You just need to implement it and come back with more specific issues.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Ok, my current issue is that the two sides are both producer and consumer: the client side could produce new data received from remote services throught callback and these data would be enqueued; at the same time, the client side may be the consumer because it consumes other data in the same queue (received by clients) and sends them to one or more remote services through the "generated proxy".

Comment: If you need a reliable queuing then consider msmq.